# How to connect to SMSC server over SMPP protocol?

Tags: java, sms-gateway, smpp

Respected All! I'm working on a project where we are developing an SMS-based disaster management system.
we have to send a request to an SMSC server over SMPP protocol to broadcast an SMS to all of its Subscribers. The cellular company has provided us with the IP/port, username and pasword to connect to their SMSC server.
I'm a bit confused on what steps should be followed to connect to their SMSC server?
kindly someone answer my following questions:
1) How to connect to the SMSC server over SMPP protocol?
2) Do we have to create our own SMPP server to send request to the SMSC server?
3) If the answer to Question# 2 is yes, then how to send request to SMSC server from SMPP server?
Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"If your provider uses the HTTP Protocol to have sms sent over to them then you would need to use HTTP POST/GET method. On the other hand if your provider uses the SMPP (Short Message Peer to Peer) Protocol you would have to use the same to connect to them."-[Source](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/171290/sending-sms-through-a-java-program#)

So, it looks like the provider is using SMPP protocol. That's means you have to set up a SMSC connection. You would need to use a Java API for this, download these [libraries](https://github.com/OpenSmpp/opensmpp) in your project. There should be documentation on how to set things up in the Java documentation with the download. gl

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Self_Taught_Programmer! I'll update this post after confirming this from the provider! Thanks again! :)

Comment: ! I've updated my question, now can you please explain me a little further?

Comment: [As an additional info] The most popular Java library for using SMPP protocol is [**Cloudhopper SMPP**](https://github.com/fizzed/cloudhopper-smpp) which is (quote) "_Real-world used library by [**Twitter**](https://about.twitter.com/) across nearly every SMSC vendor and mobile operator around the world._"

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the Open Source Mobicents SMSC server, which supports SMPP, SIP and SS7/SIGTRAN interfaces, as well as HTTP REST APIs via Restcomm.

In fact you may want to consider promptly building the SMS handling logic with the Restcomm Visual Designer and use the External Service feature to integrate with the rest of your business logic.

https://code.google.com/p/smscgateway/ 
http://www.restcomm.com/